Tic-Tac-Toe How to change gameboard array
I'm currently working on a Tic-Tac-Toe game for the odin project. The requirement for now is to get the game running purely on the console. Here's the code I've written so far:
const board = {
    a:[ "", "", ""],
    b:[ "", "", ""],
    c: [ "", "", ""]
}
function gameBoard() {
    
    const getBoard = () => board;
    const putToken = (gridItem) => {
        if (gridItem === "") {
        gridItem = game.getActivePlayer().token;
        }
    }
    const printBoard = () => console.log(board);
    return {
         getBoard, printBoard, putToken
        }
}

function gameController(playerOneName = "Player One", playerTwoName = "Player Two") {
    const boards = gameBoard();
    const players = [
        {
        name: playerOneName,
        token: "O"
    },
    {
        name: playerTwoName,
        token: "X"
    }
    ];

    let activePlayer = players[0];

    const switchPlayerTurn = () => {
        activePlayer = activePlayer === players[0] ? players[1] : players[0]
    }
    const getActivePlayer = () => activePlayer;
    
    const printNewRound = () => {
        boards.printBoard();
        console.log(`${getActivePlayer().name}'s turn.`)
    }
    const playRound = (gridItem) => {
       boards.putToken(gridItem);
       switchPlayerTurn();
       printNewRound();
        }

        printNewRound();

        return {
            playRound, getActivePlayer
        }
    }
    const game = gameController();


I'm currently having trouble trying to execute a player's turn to input his mark 'O' 'X' onto the gameboard.
I tried running
game.playRound(board.a[1]) , which will run gameBoard().putToken(board.a[1]),
which i had hoped to change board.a[1] into the active player's token which is 'O'. However, when i tried logging the supposedly updated gameboard, nothing has changed. I'm not sure what went wrong because I tried manually running board.a[1] = game.getActivePlayer().token in the console and it worked fine. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong ? Thank you !

board.a[1] is just a string, so the function argument holds a copy of that, and the original is not affected. Compare to how let gridItem = board.a[1]; gridItem = "something new" also won't affect the board.

hi, thank you for your answer! I'm trying to implement this change in my code now.

There is no code that mutates the board. The assignment you do to gridItem just assigns to a local variable with that name, not to anything in the board data structure.
This call you make:
game.playRound(board.a[1]);

will read the value found on the board, which is then passed as value to a local variable named gridItem. You cannot update the board with that information. You could fix this by passing the name of the cell you want to target. So replace the above call by this one:
game.playRound("a1");

Now playRound will have a gridItem that is that name, and will pass it on to putToken. And there you should analyse that string to access the board:
const putToken = (gridItem) => {
    const [row, col] = gridItem; // Take the two characters
    if (board[row][col] === "") { 
        // Mutate the board:
        board[row][col] = game.getActivePlayer().token;
    }
}

With those two changes it will work.
Other remarks
Not a problem, but:

you can avoid the global variable board and have it as local variable in gameBoard.

you have boards as variable name in gameControler, while really it is just one board, so drop the plural.

Use semicolons consistently, also for return statements and const declarations.


Updated:


function gameBoard() {
    // Can be local:
    const board = {
        a: [ "", "", ""],
        b: [ "", "", ""],
        c: [ "", "", ""]
    };

    const getBoard = () => board;
    const putToken = (gridItem) => {
        const [row, col] = gridItem; // Take the two characters
        if (board[row][col] === "") { 
            // Mutate the board:
            board[row][col] = game.getActivePlayer().token;
        }
    };
    const printBoard = () => console.log(board);
    return {
        getBoard, printBoard, putToken
    };
}

function gameController(playerOneName = "Player One", playerTwoName = "Player Two") {
    const board = gameBoard();
    const players = [{
        name: playerOneName,
        token: "O"
    }, {
        name: playerTwoName,
        token: "X"
    }];
    let activePlayer = players[0];

    const switchPlayerTurn = () => {
        activePlayer = activePlayer === players[0] ? players[1] : players[0]
    };
    const getActivePlayer = () => activePlayer;
    const printNewRound = () => {
        board.printBoard();
        console.log(`${getActivePlayer().name}'s turn.`)
    };
    const playRound = (gridItem) => {
        board.putToken(gridItem);
        switchPlayerTurn();
        printNewRound();
    };
    
    printNewRound();
    return {
        playRound, getActivePlayer
    };
}

const game = gameController();
game.playRound("a1"); // Pass some reference to the cell




Hi @trincot, thank you so much for the answer! I'll try implementing this now! Just so I'm clear, I have to pass "a1" into playRound(), does this mean I need to declare variables for each cell of the gameboard ? for example const a1 = board.a[0], const a2 = board.a[1] and so on ?

nvm i just answered my own question by working it in my code lol. Thank you!

You're welcome.  If you wish to do so, you can also mark the answer as accepted, but it is optional.
